# How to build wordpress site which will have location based services & products?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Even though I could use woocommerce for services & products, how to add location to them? I want users to select their location first, then only products & services will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

To ask customer to enter location before showing anything probably does not provide a very good user experience. You may want to take a look at [WC_goelocation class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Geolocation.html) which allow you to detect the IP address of the user and then identify the geolocation based on the IP.